# Azure Databricks scheduled job is executed successfully but data is not loaded into destination

Tags: azure-databricks

log is showing like command took 49.03 minutes ,i can see status of job as "succeeded" but data is not loaded.

Kindly help me out with possible assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

In the log file, please check for the number of records processed and loaded in each step. Have a look in the tables used in the join.

Perform more detailed analysis by, executing the steps manually and analyse the outcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Raj, Thanks for giving reply, i will show sreen shot.  one more help, could you help me on " can we rerun the job before dates like i am facing issue data is on 29/12/2019, can i run only that particular date job?:"

Comment: when i open logfile , it is  showing last 3 days log files but not the date what  i want , Raj

Comment: result = rca.expand(mapper.merged)
 
for col in result:
  # round result to prevent issues with long decimals in Power BI 
  for i, week in enumerate(result[col]):
    result[col][i] = round(result[col][i], 3)
    
rca.to_csv(result = result, previous = True)
Wrote 16135 bytes.
Command took 4.27 seconds